# CardView is not working perfectly in my android app, showing different in screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragmentactivity, android-cardview, cardview

I'm using ***android.support.v7.widget.CardView*** with match_parent and wrap_content. i want to make my layout responsive for all devices. all is working fine in android studio. but when i'm installing this app to an android device or emulator it's showing like the below image.

[image: CardView ScreenShot]

but i want to make this responsive with the width and height. please help me to solve this problem.

my fragment code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorBG"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        tools:context=".LiveTV"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/news24"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/news24"
                        android:padding="10dp"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/deshebideshe"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/deshebideshe"
                        android:padding="10dp"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/jamuna"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/jamuna"
                        android:padding="10dp"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/satv"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/satv"
                        android:padding="10dp"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/jagobanglatv"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/jagobanglatv"
                        android:padding="10dp"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/nrbtv"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/nrbtv"
                        android:padding="10dp"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/rtvmusic"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/rtvmusic"
                        android:padding="10dp"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/qtv"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/qtv"
                        android:padding="10dp"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/panvisiontv"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/panvisiontv"
                        android:padding="10dp"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/millennium"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/millennium"
                        android:padding="10dp"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/btvworld"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/btvworld"
                        android:padding="10dp"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/probashibangla"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/probashibangla"
                        android:padding="10dp"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by responsive?

Comment: Do you know how to use ConstraintLayout?

Comment: yes @UmangBurman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make below change in your cardview

- make `CardView` width **`android:layout_width="0dp"`**
- Use **`android:layout_weight="1"`** in your `CardView`

Try this

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorBG"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        tools:context=".LiveTV"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/news24"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/news24"
                        android:padding="10dp"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/deshebideshe"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/deshebideshe"
                        android:padding="10dp"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/jamuna"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/jamuna"
                        android:padding="10dp"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/satv"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/satv"
                        android:padding="10dp"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/jagobanglatv"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/jagobanglatv"
                        android:padding="10dp"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"

                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/nrbtv"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/nrbtv"
                        android:padding="10dp"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/rtvmusic"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/rtvmusic"
                        android:padding="10dp"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/qtv"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/qtv"
                        android:padding="10dp"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/panvisiontv"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/panvisiontv"
                        android:padding="10dp"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/millennium"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/millennium"
                        android:padding="10dp"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/btvworld"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/btvworld"
                        android:padding="10dp"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/probashibangla"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/probashibangla"
                        android:padding="10dp"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**BTW**

As per my advise you can use [**`RecyclerView`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) with [**`GridLayoutManager`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager)

here is the Good article for how to use [**`RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager`**](https://www.journaldev.com/13792/android-gridlayoutmanager-example)

Comment: You are the real hero. thanks for your help. is this layout will responsive with all display size?

Comment: @Liton go with  RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager as iadwise in my answer

Answer (score 0):

add these lines in your linearLayout which is having two cardView

```
android:weightSum="2"
```

and add this line in both cardView

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

and make cardView width 0dp like this

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

Comment: thanks a lot... i got helped from another person. and your answer is correct. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

i think your cardview doesnt look perfectly because of the size of images and i think if you use recyclerview and adapter by gridlayout manager will solve your proplem

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,numberofColumns));
```

in the top code if you put 2 instead of numberofColumns it will put two cardivew 
in every line and it will solve your problem,

if you dont want to use recyclerview you should give size to
   android:layout_width
and   android:layout_height
of imageView
and then make the xml layout in 6 different usual size

hdpi , xhdpi , xxhdpi , xxxhdpi , sw600dp and sw720dp

and it doenst look like a good solution

i hope it help you (:

Comment: i think you found your answer and my answer is like that our friend said the best solution is . to use gridlayoutmanager